# Move files into a new folder with today's date

Tags: powershell, file-move, create-directory

I have 20 reports that come weekly. I have a powershell scrip that will create a folder with the date on it. I would like to create a script that will create a new folder each time it runs and then move all the xlsx file into that new folder. 
For the folder creation I am using

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "S:\***\***\Reporting\Export\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
```

The road block I am running into is finding a way to specify the new folder as the target path for the moving of files.

Comment: assign the path to a $Var & use that $Var in the various cmdlets. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the newly created directory in a variable use that variable for the `Destination` parameter when moving:

```
$destination = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "S:\SOC\Reports\Reporting\Export\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
Move-Item -Path "$SourcePath\*" -Destination $destination
```